# The kanji 一 in 神の一手

Tags: kanji

In the game of go (囲碁{いご｝), the expression 神｛かみ｝の一手｛いって｝ refers to the perfect game of go, and it is referenced multiple times in the anime Hikaru no Go.

My question: Why 神の一手 and not 神の手? I can't find the kanji 手 alongside 一 on any online dictionary.

Comment: [Here's one online dictionary.](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1MUJ一手)

Answer (score 3):

According to [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%80%E6%89%8B):

> 一手{いって}: move (in game); method; single-handed; monopoly

From the Japanese definition, it mostly refers to moves in 囲碁 and 将棋. Since it is a board game term, it makes sense in 神の一手 (god's go moves/method) more than 神の手 (hand of god).

For more details in Japanese: [Yahoo Japanese Dictionary](http://dic.search.yahoo.co.jp/search?p=%E4%B8%80%E6%89%8B&stype=full&aq=-1&oq=&ei=UTF-8)

Comment: 手 itself can mean a move (in a game) but it refers to one certain move, so 一手.